# Solve a basic solution and the column manipulation

Tags: linear-algebra

Solve a basic solution.

\begin{align*}A=\begin{array}{cccc} 1 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 \\ 2 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\\end{array};\end{align*}

here eliminate First element of row2 and row3.

\begin{align*}\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 1 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\ 0 & -2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 3 & 1 \\\end{array}\right)\end{align*}

here I can directly calculate for a basic solution. $x_2= 0,x_1=x_3-x_4$ so, the solution vector is $\{4,0,1,-3\}$

However, here seems I've made a wrong calculation(something conflicts with Determinant?)

I add column1 to column 2, column 3, column 4.

\begin{align*}\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 3 & 1 \\\end{array}\right)\end{align*}

Here $x_1=0$, then it's wrong answer? Where goes wrong and why, cant do the column manipulation?

Comment: You cannot define the determinant if your matrix is not an $n \times n$ matrix; it is not defined. And notice that in this case of an $n \times n$ matrix you can have either $0,1$, or $\infty$ -many solutions; not just one solution.

Comment: @DBF Can I from the second matrix get the right answer?

Comment: I think the problem is that by manipulating columns, you are changing the structure of the solution space of the rows; any operation other than either of: i)Adding a multiple of row i to row j ii)Exchanging rows or iii)(Can't remember the third) will change the structure (meaning the solutions) to the row space. Note that the row space and column space have the same dimension, but they are not equal to each other.

Comment: Third operation is multiplying a row by a constant; any other operation on your matrix will change the solution of the row space.

Answer (score 1):

Only row operations preserve the solution space, column operations do not.